# Crazy algorithm to chose right color in rgb?

Tags: c#, algorithm, colors, rgb

Can someone help me with this crazy algorithm please? I need to find some exact color (R,G,B model) pixel in pictures. And I need one algorithm for more pictures. I need to find one of 3 good colors against 9 bad colors in every picture with one algorithm. Do you think it's possible?

[image: First picture]

In picture you can see 3 good colors (R,G,B model) (yellow background) and 9 bad colors (green background). And I need an algorithm to chose one of the good colors when I will compare all these colors.

I have got 3 this pictures with different good and bad colors. And I need to find one algorithm, for all these pictures, that will choose one from good colors before all of bad colors in specific picture.

[image]

[image]

One algorithm, that when I use it for first set of numbers will chose each one of good (yellow) colors. and when I apply this same algorithm for second picture, it will choose one of good (yellow) colors from set of numbers for picture two and same algorithm for third picture (set of numbers).

You can find numbers in written form in xlsx file here: [xlsx file](http://www.speedyshare.com/5aqD8/algorithm.xlsx)

Do you think it's possible?

EDIT: i make some change in picture 3 ... and i upload new xlsx file

I compare individual pixel in bmp file something like

```
for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
            {
                GetPixel(x, y).Color
            }
        }
```

and i get 3 numbers (x, y).R, (x, y).G, (x, y).B

And im finding most red pixels (there is red dot in picture) but with different lighting this red pixels can have different levels of R,G,B model. In picture 3 you can see that when is R level bigger then G and B lvl

```
if ((R-30>G) && (R-30>B))
```

it will find me only good colors (yellow background) in picture 3. But when in picture arent this colors like in picture 2.. i need use something else to find good color. But i need to combine these conditions to one algorithm that when i use for picture 3 it will find me good colors (yellow background) for this picture and when i use it on second picture it will find my good pixels for second picture...

EDIT2:

[image][image][image]

So here are 3 pictures. In pictures is one red thing (in yellow circle) but with different lighting. And interference (green circle). So pixels in yellow circle have got RGB model like are numbers with yellow bacground (good color) and in green circle have got RGB model like are numbers with green bacground (bad color).

Comment: Prepare for the imminent flood of down votes. You need to add more content to your question. Show us what code you have.

Comment: i dont have any code for this.. i think im not so smart for this.. therefore I ask here

Comment: So, this is a C# program you're trying to write? Or is this excel? You have not made any effort at all?

Answer (score 0):

How is the data represented in your program?

I'm just going to assume that these values are represented as an integer array `p`, with three elements. Make two methods:

1. `concatenate(int[] p) { string.Join("", p); }`
2. `comparergbs(string p, int[][] rgbs) { /* you fill this part in */ }`

Then since your values that are `[111,222,333]` become `"111222333"`, you can compare them using just a string representation to determine membership.

### Edit

Or, if you're really clever with the code, you can pack the set of integer values into a 32 bit integer like @paddy suggested.

Comment: i think i must compare it as integer... because it depends on whether particular numbers larger or smaller.... Like in picture one is good color 115,115,115 .. but in picture 3 is it bad color. Because there is better color for example when is R bigger than otther numbers.

Comment: I thought you're trying to determine if a color `p` is in the list of bad colors or good colors. If you compare them as integers, the solution is most certainly going to be slower. You're still not telling us exactly how the data is stored, which will ultimately affect the solution.

Comment: With respect, @alvonellos, if you convert each colour into a string, *that* will be a performance hit.  Comparing them as integers is natural, since the data will already be in integer form.  A 24-bit RGB value can be held in a single 32-bit integer.  Also, I think the OP is asking about how to select the best match out of allowed colours.

Comment: @paddy, either way he is going to have to do some conversion to find whether one pixel value is in another pixel value. Pardon me for not being specific when I said that it was going to be slower comparing integers -- I was imagining the nightmare that is a new coder trying to iterate through one column to find a yellow value, then iterate through another column to find a green value, and then finally iterating through yet another column to find a blue value. I'm rusty on time complexity but, what's that, O(n^3) worst case O(n^4) since he has to iterate through each yellow? "Slow" he'll say.

Comment: If he is trying to find the closest match to a given RGB value in some string/integer/null pointer value (I'm joking), then he will need, for each element in his array (forgetting the conversion) find the manhattan distance between two strings, storing the lowest value thus so far. Then he would have to do some further manipulation to figure out if that guessed number is "bad" or "good". That operation, I believe, will be O(n).

Comment: So, @paddy, am I completely off base here? O(n) < O(n^3), right? Oh, and, he does say "I need to find some exact value."

Comment: @alvonellos I think that both the question and answer here are not sufficient.  You may or may not have misinterpreted the question, and I can't even tell anymore.  The more edits the question takes, the less clear it becomes.  In any case, computing Manhattan distance (or similar measures) is *not* O(N^3).  It is constant time.  Or, if you choose N to be the number of colours compared, rather than image pixels, we can say it's O(N).

Comment: I know computing the manhattan/hamming distance is constant time. I was referring to the nightmare he is going to end up coding if he loops through three or four times.

Comment: @alvonellos My point is that you don't need to loop three or four times.  Each colour is simply a colour, whether you represent it as a string, an array, some RGB structure, or a single integer.  You compute the distance between it and some other colour in constant time, and that's all.

Comment: @paddy, I know! If you reread the discombobulated nonsense that is his post, you'll see that looping through several times is **EXACTLY** what he is tending towards. That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @alvonellos I think I'm just going to stop commenting on this, and leave you to it =)